# How can I start rpcbind -i on startup?

Tags: raspbian, boot

I need have the rpcbind deamon running in 'insecure' mode all the time. What is the right way to do this using raspbian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a script in /etc/init.d and use update-rc.d to register the script, that way it will start at boot and you can make it close properly at shutdown.

See this blog post for instructions and an example script [www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit /etc/rc.local and include your command before its exit statement.

Then `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local` to enable it

And `sudo reboot` to reboot and see if that has worked out for you.